# ASP.NET Core layout page multiple sidebar menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, menu, sidebar, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

So here's the problem, user can select one of six links, something like this 
[image]

after he select specific link for example Link 1 he should be redirected to home page with sidebar menu looking like this:

[image]

If he select for example Link 2 his menu should look like this:

[image]

Anyway, i got no idea how to achieve this since my menu is located inside _Layout.cshtml, could View Component feature help me with this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution myself using viewComponent feature.

First of all i had to reconfigure my default route inside Startup.cs to look like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "defaultLink",
        template: "{link='Link1'}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

After that inside layout I invoked viewComponent like this:

```
// invoke viewComponent in layout and pass url parameter to it    
@Component.Invoke("SidebarMenu", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["link"])
```

and my viewComponent method looks like :

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string link)
{
    switch (link)
    {
        case "Link1":
            return View("_Link1Menu");
        case "Link2":
            return View("_Link2Menu");             
        default:
            return View("_Link1Menu");
    }
}
```

_Link1Menu view looks like this:

```
<li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/Link1/Home/SomeMethod">
                Test1MenuLink1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/Link1/Home/SomeOtherMethod">
                Test1MenuLink2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and _Link2Menu view looks like this:

```
<li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/Link1/Home/SomeMethod">
                Test2MenuLink1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/Link1/Home/SomeOtherMethod">
                Test2MenuLink2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

After this, when u hit URL /Link1/Home/Index - u'll get menu from _Link1Menu view, and when u hit URL /Link2/Home/Index - u'll get menu from _Link2Menu view...