# Asp.net Sidebar with different components for each page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all I have the worst English ever and want to thanks for helping ! :)

Here's the idea:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="background-color:darkgray;width:30%">
    <h2>Side Barrr</h2>
    <!--this is where goes the different components for each page-->
</div>
```

This sidebar is shown in pageOne and pageTwo, but in pageOne it has

```
<img src="imgs/img.png" alt="img" />
<a href="somelink">somelink</a>
```

and in pageTwo it has

```
<p>Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.</p>
```

I can make a personalized sidebar for each page but I want to use the sidebar base code and inject the component I want to based on page, instead of repeating the base sidebar code.
I know there is view component in asp.net core but it can't be used with midlewares...

I hope is clear if not let me know I will asked in a different approach

Comment: If your using webforms  add master page  place content placeholder inside  sidebar ,in content pages u can  add different content

Comment: arun !! thanks body for replying back ! No I'm not using webforms... I fund someone asking the same question here [Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105888/asp-net-5-mvc-6-layout-page-multiple-sidebar-menu) I guess my solution is "web components". And sorry for the duplicate question :)

Comment: If it is MVC you can use RenderSection in layout and change accordingly in views